# Pass PHP variable to AngularJS and use it to populate a list in the script

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a search form that I want to make dynamic from a database. The search form relies on an external AngularJS script from data is stored.

```
    angular.module('sortApp', [])

    .controller('mainController', function($scope) {
      $scope.sortType     = 'name'; // set the default sort type
      $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order

      // create the list of sushi rolls 
      $scope.engineers = [
        { engineer: 'Mark Smith', team: 'Team 1'  },
        { engineer: 'Sean Barry', team: 'Team 2'  },
        { engineer: 'Ben Matthews', team: 'Team 3'  },
        { engineer: 'Jayson Balls', team: 'Team 4' },
        { engineer: 'Dolton Tims', team: 'Team 5' }
  ];

});
```

That's the script code. The logic is fairly simple, I would use a loop to go through all the results of an SQL query, store that in a PHP variable and send that variable to Javascript on the 'engineer' and 'team' parts. This would then show everything I specify from the database instead of having to enter the details in the JS file manually every time a change is made.

I know how to retrieve results from an database using PHP. I need all of the results gathered from a query to be stored in a PHP variable and send that PHP variable with the varied results to the script.

Anyone have an idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Which part is your problem? How to write output using PHP? How to encode PHP outputs as JSON? Or how to query a database using PHP? Or reading an AJAX response in JS? The questino is much to vague – there are a lot of different ways to solve such kind of problems. What do you got so far? P.S. There is no PHP in this question…

Comment: I've updated the question. I know the mysql part, I just need to send the gathered results from a query to the Javascript file so that it can auto-populate itself. I don't have any PHP code because I haven't done that part yet

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send any data from php to javascript. Instead, you have to get data with a javascript AJAX request. Data should be JSON encoded on server side.

See php JSON encode documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Also Angular $http.get documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a REST API interface to your backend environment, format it as JSON, and then use AngularJS $resource service to access the data.